# python file creation is giving some error

Tags: python-3.x

```
result={'name':12,'age':23}
file_name="SpaceX_"+date_format+"_data"+".json"
# load into a file
json.dump( result, open( file_name, 'w' ) )
```

> I get this error     json.dump( result, open( file_name, 'w' ) )
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SpaceX_03/21/22_data.json'

Comment: you need to remove the slash from the filename, otherwise the OS will look for file 22_data.json inside a folder path which probably does not exist, hence the error. try data_format = date_format.replace('/','_') before defining file_name

Comment: It is giving me the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import json
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
date_format = today.strftime("%m.%d.%y")
result = {'name': 12, 'age': 23}
file_name = "SpaceX_"+date_format+"_data"+".json"  # load into a file with

with open(file_name, "x") as f:
    json.dump(result, f)
```

Your issue was on this line `date_format = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")`. As `/` was tring to go down a directory (or into a new folder). E.g the path `folder1/folder2` is saying to go to `folder1` then to `folder2` which is in `folder1`. Which was fixed by changing `/` to `.` in your date string

Just for the future, remember to avoid `/` in file names completely

Comment: Yell out if this doesn't work

Comment: Same Error "No such file or directory". I tried both approaches.

Comment: ```import json
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
date_format = today.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
result = {'name': 12, 'age': 23}
file_name = "SpaceX_"+date_format+"_data"+".json"

# load into a file
with open(file_name, "x") as f:
    json.dump(result, f)```

Comment: Fixed, please see edit